# Checkmarx SQL Injection Vulnerability saying - This input then flows through the code, into a query and to the database server - without sanitization

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkmarx

Full issue Description is - *The application
constructs this SQL query by embedding an untrusted string into the query without proper sanitization. The
concatenated string is submitted to the database, where it is parsed and executed accordingly. An attacker would be able to inject arbitrary syntax and data into the SQL query, by crafting a malicious
payload and providing it via the input SelectedValue this input is then read by the Button_Click method. This input then flows through the code, into a
query and to the database server - without sanitization. This may enable an SQL Injection attack*

The issue is saying am using the value from dropdown (listControl.SelectedValue;) in SqlDataAdapter ( Adapter.Fill( Result );) without proper sanitization. Could you please help me to resolve this. This is the code

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        QueryData data = new ReportConfigReader().GetQueryData(ReportCategoryListBox.SelectedValue, ReportNameListBox.SelectedValue);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (QueryParameter parameter in data.Parameters)
        {
            object Value = null;
            if (parameter.ControlID == "NA")
            {
                Value = parameter.Value;
                parameters[parameter.Name] = Value;
                continue;
            }

            Control ctrl = null;
            if (parameter.ControlID.ToUpper() == "REPORTTINSVN" || parameter.ControlID.ToUpper() == "REPORTTAN" ||
                parameter.ControlID.ToUpper() == "REPORTMISSINGOLBT") 
                ctrl = ReportParamsUpdatePanel.FindControl(parameter.ControlID).Controls[1];
            else if (parameter.ControlID.ToUpper() == "REPORTCLIENTID")
                ctrl = ReportParamsUpdatePanel.FindControl(parameter.ControlID).Controls[5];
            else
                ctrl = ReportParamsUpdatePanel.FindControl(parameter.ControlID).Controls[3];

            var listControl = ctrl as ListControl;
            var checkbox = ctrl as CheckBox;
            var textbox = ctrl as TextBox;

            if (listControl != null)
                Value = listControl.SelectedValue;
            else if (checkbox != null)
                Value = (Convert.ToInt16(checkbox.Checked).ToString());
            else if (textbox != null)
            {
                if (textbox.TextMode == TextBoxMode.MultiLine)
                {
                    Value = Regex.Replace(textbox.Text, @" *[\r\n]+ *", ",", RegexOptions.Multiline).Trim();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Value)) Value = "ALL";
                }
                else
                {
                    Value = textbox.Text.Trim();
                }
            }

            switch (parameter.Type)
            {
                case ParameterType.String:
                    break;
                case ParameterType.Int:
                    Value = int.Parse((string)Value);
                    break;
                case ParameterType.DateTime:
                    Value = DateTime.Parse((string)Value);
                    break;
            }
            parameters[parameter.Name] = Value;
        }

        DataTable reportData = GetReport(data.QueryName, parameters);
            
    }
    
    public DataTable GetReport( string SPName, Dictionary<string, object> SPParams ) {
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(SPName);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Cmd.CommandTimeout = 900;                               
        foreach ( string ParamName in SPParams.Keys ) {
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{ParamName}", SPParams[ParamName]);
        }
        Cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter( Cmd );
        DataTable Result = new DataTable();
        Adapter.Fill( Result );
        return Result;
    }
```

Comment: It looks OK to me. The scanner just isn't smart enough to be able to determine that you ended up putting all of the user input into parameters. BTW, [AddWithValue is evil](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and you have disposable resources that you are not disposing.

Comment: I can't see what is in `ReportConfigReader().GetQueryData()`, but that seems to take unchecked user data and does some kind of lookup.  Otherwise Crowcoder is correct.

Comment: @tgolisch ReportConfigReader().GetQueryData() is reading  data from an XML file which contains details of StoreProcedure name , parameter name to store procedure  and ID of UI html tag which we need to take value for the parameters